# SSIS package data transfer from developer to web edition database at two different locations

Tags: ssis

I have two sql server database at two different locations. Source is developer edition of sql server and destination is web edition of sql server. Can i create ssis package in developer edition, for data transfer from developer to web edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes<sup>*</sup>, you can create an SSIS package in the Developer Edition and it will transfer data between the developer edition database and the web edition just fine. It will be a straight data transfer between two SQL Server instances.

That pesky asterisk though, that might be make this a No answer. The Web edition is *not* licensed for Integration Services. There is the import/export wizard which builds an SSIS package but if you persist it and execute the package, then it will fail as the machine will report it does not have the right components installed. It's certainly nothing you can schedule. You might think that you can make an end-around and run the SSIS package from the development server but that will likely violate your license as the dev license is not supposed to communicate with production systems.

- [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

### Summary

There is no *technical* restriction preventing an SSIS package from pushing from a developer edition to an web edition but there is likely a *legal* restriction for doing so.

YMMV, IANAL, consult your licensing agent.